# Correct usage of sqlalchemy scoped_session with python asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

I'm building an app using asyncio. I will be using sqlalchemy as the orm.
From what i understand scoped_session associates a session with a thread so they don't with each other's operations.
Now since asyncio works on a single thread and I believe scoped_session will not work correctly which will cause problems.
What would be the correct way to use sqlalchemy sessions with asyncio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends on your code.

In general you can use [sessionmaker](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_api.html?highlight=sessionmaker#sqlalchemy.orm.session.sessionmaker) for creating session factory and using it on your own.

If your code has implicit context you may use `scoped_session` with custom `scopefunc` as shown in [example](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/contextual.html?highlight=scoped_session#using-custom-created-scopes).

Implicit context may utilize [asyncio.Task.current_task()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.current_task) call but you need to find a way for scoped session destruction also.

Comment: What is the default behaviour for scoped_session destruction? Does it get destroyed when the thread is closed? Wouldn't it also in that case destroy when the task is finished?

Comment: `scoped_session` has no destructor, sorry. That's why you need signal subscription in the example above.

Comment: What kind of signal subscription do I need to provide in the ```scopefunc``` parameter of the scoped_session function, if I am using the ```aiohttp``` framework? @AndrewSvetlov

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use sqlalchemy with asyncio. The SQL Alchemy API is all blocking and incompatible with asyncio. http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2015/02/15/asynchronous-python-and-databases/

You *can* use SQL Alchemy asynchronously with [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) though, as long as you can find a gevent-compatible driver for your database. And gevent greenlents map nicely to `scoped_session`.

EDIT: actually, it looks like you *can* use SQL Alchemy with asyncio as long as you can find an asyncio-compatible driver for your database, such as https://github.com/aio-libs/aiopg . As for `scoped_session`, use `current_task` and destroy it on your web framework's request end.

Comment: I'm not looking to make sqlalchemy async. What I want to do is keep the tasks from using the same session at the same time i.e. The tasks should not be sharing sessions.

Comment: Except you are assigning each tasks item to a new thread, using a normal sqlalchemy session i.e **Session = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine) session = Session()** might be all you need. You create it before the task ends and close it after the tasks is finished.